# SQL Server Convert datetime to date without null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, ssms

I have a stored procedure like so:

```
select 
    TransactionDate 
from 
    (select 
         cast(TransactionDate as Date) as TransactionDate
     from RetailTransaction) t
```

However this makes the `TransactionDate` column of the outer-select nullable, while `RetailTransaction.TransactionDate` column is not null.

`RetailTransaction.TransactionDate` definition / design:

[image]

Inner Select:

[image: Inner Select]

Outer Select:

[image: Outer Select]

Even after adding `isnull` or `coalesce` SQL Server / SSMS still shows that the outer selects `TransactionDate` column is still nullable.

```
select 
    TransactionDate 
from 
    (select 
         isnull(cast(TransactionDate as Date), getdate()) as TransactionDate
     from 
         RetailTransaction) t
```

[image: Example 2]

How do I make the `TransactionDate` column non nullable?

Note that the database is on Azure with compatibility level 100 (SQL Server 2008).

EDIT:

Adding an `isnull` on the outer select still make the column nullable to an outer-nested-query:

[image: outer-nested-query]

Comment: What do you mean by the column is still "nullable?"

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen See the tool tips, the data type of that column is `(date, null)`, when it should be `(date, not null)`. Compare the Inner Select example with the Outer Select example

Comment: You control this from your table definition.  Can you add that?

Comment: The `TransactionDate` column in the table `RetailTransaction` is `(datetime, not null)`. The resulting data set after converting to date is `(date, null)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Updated the question

Comment: So, I don't have any concrete answers here but just guesses as to how intellisense works and why it might not _actually_ matter. Intellisense might be designed to just automatically assume that the result of any function (e.g CAST, CONVERT, ISNULL) _might_ be NULL (since it might not be designed to work out whether a function may be null based on inputs). This, however, may not _actually_ reflect what happens in actuality. If the result can never be null, it doesn't _really_ matter what intellisense says about it.

Comment: @ZLK The reason why this is an issue is because I am consuming this stored procedure using EntityFramework (C#) and it is detecting that that column is nullable, making my types nullable. I think I have come up with a workaround whereby I am doing an `Insert into @temptable` with TransactionDate set as `(date, not null)` and then selecting it.

Comment: That's probably the easiest solution. Alternatives would be something like manually changing the datatype in C# or I guess adding a persisted computed column to your table that converts the datetime to date and is already not null (which may be useful to you if you find yourself regularly casting it as a date anyway).

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but if the column is non-nullable in he first place, why do you add `isnull` or `coalesce`? if it's a `DateTime` value that's non-nullable, casting to `Date` will never return null, so the `isnull/coalesce` is redundant.

Comment: Why do you cast the datetime column? Is it to remove any timestamps?

Comment: @MatsMagnem Yes, But I need it to be strongly-typed

Comment: @ZoharPeled The `CAST` turns the column into `(datetime, null)` and I need the column to be `(datetime, not null)`

Comment: I see. I've learned something new today, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comment I did some digging and testing, and even though I couldn't find official documentation about it, you are correct and the casting to date makes the value nullable, even if the datetime is not nullable. I've even tried a different method by using `datetimefromparts` to create a date data type but that also changes the nullablility of the result.
So the way I see it, you have two options:

The first option is to add a persisted computed column to the table that will hold the date value of the transaction date. It has to be persisted to be non nullable:

```
ALTER TABLE RetailTransaction
    ADD TransactionDateOnly AS CAST(TransactionDate As Date) PERSISTED NOT NULL;
```

and then your query looks like this:

```
SELECT TransactionDateOnly as TransactionDate
FROM RetailTransaction
```

The other option would be to declare a table variable with a non-nullable date column, select the cast results into it, and then select from the table variable:

```
DECLARE @Target AS TABLE
(
    TransactionDate Date NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO @Target(TransactionDate)
SELECT CAST(TransactionDate as Date) 
FROM RetailTransaction) t
```

And then your select looks like this:

```
SELECT TransactionDate 
FROM  @Target
```

Both ways will get you a non-nullable date as a result, but I think the persisted computed column option should probably yield better performance on the select, because it doesn't require that extra insert...select.

Comment: Thank you for your well thought out answer with actual solutions.

Comment: I decided to go with your method of putting my result set into a temporary table and then just returning that.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes the reason it is showing Nullable for not nullable column is because you are making your outer select as computed based on isnull condition and others.

In this table Email is not nullable column and now if I give Isnull condition in inner query it will be like this.

[image]

Now if I don't give any condition it will be like this.

[image]

You can refer to this link as well for detailed explanation.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114260/why-is-a-not-null-computed-column-considered-nullable-in-a-view

Comment: I don't think this answer is accurate... And the link you've provided explicitly says "An expression that is nullable can be turned into a nonnullable one by specifying ISNULL(check_expression, constant), where the constant is a nonnull value substituted for any null result." so this doesn't address that...

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to put the ISNULL on the outer query and add an alias so that you don't lose the name

```
select 
    isnull(TransactionDate, GETDATE()) as TransactionDate
from ( 
    select 
        Cast(TransactionDate as Date) as TransactionDate
    from RetailTransaction
) t
```

That way SQL will realise that the field cannot be null.  This should nicely inform any ORM that this field should not be mapped to a nullable type.

Comment: Please see updated question. This solution does not work for me.

Comment: @Minijack is it a computed column?

Comment: No. TransactionDate is `datetime not null`